# Suddenly websites load forever

Tags: dns, internet-connection, network-adapter

I have a weird problem in my apartment.

When I am browsing...if I go to any sites hosted in the US (I am right now in Germany)....the site keeps on loading forever..but if i restart my browser it loads perfectly.
During normal browsing suddenly page loads forever...(even tho the network is connected)

This is more frequent in Windows...but less problems in my ubuntu linux firefox.

Is this a DNS issue...? (Tried giving Google DNS with no effect  )

How is it working better in Ubuntu firefox...How does the browser restart help ?

Can somebody please help....

Comment: Can you confirm that this happens with multiple different browsers in Windows?

Comment: Hi... yes it happens in firefox and chrome...it will be working at first...but after say 5min...all of a sudden pages start loading forever...

Answer (score 0):

If it's in Windows, it could be a corrupted file in the browser cache. Your browser will call from the cache before it tries the server. It can depend on the sequence you open sites in or if you have preloading tabs, a standard site like webmail etc. Chrome also has a preloading thing. If you hold down the shift key when you click Reload, it will get it from the server. If that helps, clear you browser caches.

You might want to reset your router to ensure it's not confused. Ensure its not overheating as well.

You might want to do a system scan with an online scanner to ensure you don't have some sort of virus. But again - that's a Windows thing.

And you might want to try the free [DNSJumper](http://sordum.xoomsite.com/4573/dns-jumper-v1-0-4/). It allows you to experiment with DNS servers and test their speed. It also allows easy DNS switching which may be advantageous if you find one better for overseas and another for EU.

And sometimes it can be something like a flaky router your ISP is using to connect overseas. You can use an online Traceroute tool and see where the lags are happening. DNS changes may help depending on where the lag is.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you so much David for your detailed answer... I will definitely try this after reaching home.. Thanks for the DNSJumper link..Also do you know any specific online traceroute tool ?